# Google Maps infowindow don't work on marker click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API v3 geocoding service. The geocoding part works fine. I type a zip code in a textbox and then hit the submit button. Then it shows a **blue marker** at the place which I typed in the textbox. And then it loads places in a radius of 20km and display these with a **red marker**. That all works fine. But then I got some problems with the infowindow.

If I click on a marker (red or blue) it happens nothing. And I just can't figure it out. I use this code for infowindow:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {xmldata: jqXHR.responseText},
    success: function(locations, textStatus, jqXHR){

        var split = locations.split(",");

        var checkForDouble = split.filter(function(elem, pos) {
            return split.indexOf(elem) == pos;
        });

    for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
        geocoder.geocode(
            {'address': checkForDouble[i]},
            function(results, status){
                if(results != null){
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                }
            }
        );

        var infocontent = checkForDouble[i];                                        
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infocontent) {
            return function(){
                infowindow.setContent(infocontent);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, infocontent));
    }                                   
}
```

Can someone give me a hint where I made the error?

Comment: A guess because there is no other code. 1. infocontent is empty/undefined 2. (most probable) because beocode is async your marker and infowindow are not properly connected. Move your event listener and two lines for infowindow to geocode function after marker creation.

Comment: Agree with You. In my opinion second option is correct

Comment: I tested it. infocontent is not undefined. With your second solution you mean I should put the infowindow function right after the closing of `marker = new google.maps.Marker({`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need function closure on your geocoder call also.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function createMarker(address)
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
    var infocontent = address;                                        

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(infocontent);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;
}
function geocodeAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode(
        {'address': address,
        function(results, status){
            if((results != null) && (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)) {
               var marker = createMarker(address);
            } else alert("geocode failed on "+address+", status="+status);
        }
    );
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {xmldata: jqXHR.responseText},
    success: function(locations, textStatus, jqXHR){

        var split = locations.split(",");

        var checkForDouble = split.filter(function(elem, pos) {
            return split.indexOf(elem) == pos;
        });

    for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
       geocodeAddress(checkForDouble[i]);
    }                              
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to do without changing the structure? :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `closure` around your listener because it will use your parameter in future. you have to pass data to anonymous function.
With this code you can get your structure.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {xmldata: jqXHR.responseText},
    success: function(locations, textStatus, jqXHR){

        var split = locations.split(",");

        var checkForDouble = split.filter(function(elem, pos) {
            return split.indexOf(elem) == pos;
        });

    for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
        geocoder.geocode(
            {'address': checkForDouble[i]},
            function(results, status){
                if(results != null){
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                }
            }
        );

        (function (infocontent){
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    infowindow.setContent(infocontent);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            });
        })(checkForDouble[i])

    }                                   
}
```